# Linux ignores ECHO REQUESTs that come from one interface but are within the IP range of the other

Tags: icmp

[image: A Linux notebook with WIFI and Ethernet connections and a PC visible both directly from the Ethernet and via a router from the WIFI. ECHO REQUESTs are send from the PC via the router to the WIFI address and do not get a reply from either interface]

I ping the WiFi IP of the Linux notebook from the router and it responds fine. I ping the WIFI address from a PC which is visible both directly from the LAN (eth1) and via the router from the WiFi interface(wlo1) but I get no replies. `tcpdump` shows me that it does receive `ECHO REQUESTS` but I don't see replies neither on wlo1(WiFi) nor on eth1(LAN).

Comment: Route to external subnet (or default route) via the router? If not, the system won't know where to send replies so it'll discard them

Comment: As @roaima wrote: The laptop needs a default route via the router or a dedicated route to the 10.0.0.0 network. Pleas add the output of 'route -n' on the laptop, as well as the network configuration of the routing device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've updated your diagram, and the wiring as shown almost certainly won't work. Consider a packet from 10.0.0.3 to  the WiFi interface 192.168.2.2. The packet arrives and will promptly get discarded as it's apparently arrived on the wrong interface. (WiFi is 192.168.2.0/24 but Ethernet is 10.0.0.0/24.) This is known as "reverse path filtering" and is an important security feature within a firewall. You can disable it if you really need to, but you should first reconsider your network topology.

---

(Old answer before updating the diagram)

You should make sure you have a route to the external subnet (or a default route) via your router. Otherwise the system won't know where to send replies so it will discard them.

I see that you have two default routes. This is not recommended unless they are different metrics. The default route is intended to be the route of last resort (i.e. the *default* route) for traffic with no explicitly defined route. By definition you cannot have more than one of them.

There are two exceptions, which aren't really exceptions at all:

1. where default routes have different metrics; in this case the one with the lowest metric will be used and all others will be ignored
2. where you have used namespaces or other routing table extensions to provide different default routes for different situations; in this case each situation can have only the one default route and the rule still applies

Comment: Thanks roaima! Although routing plays a huge role here it's not just another typical routing issue. See my updated drawing. I still don't understand why replies don't appear in either of the two interfaces.

Comment: You can't do what you've just drawn. It won't work.

Comment: Why does it not work???

Comment: Answer updated to address the new information you've added to your question

Comment: THANKS roaima. I would propose that I strip down my question to exclude irrelevant info and do the same to your answer (remove everything except the last paragraph). Do you agree?

Comment: I'd just leave it